# How can I apply my custom JTextField affects as default and have different affects for each state?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I am using a Nimbus LAF for my program and have created a custom JTextField with rounded borders, shading, etc, that I am very satisfied with, however I would like to be able set the affects as default so I do not have to apply it to each JTextfield. I don't mind applying it to each field the main concern I am having is I want to be able to have different affects for each state (ie: focused, not focused, disabled, enabled, etc).  Below is the code I am using currently to achieve a single custom change. Is there anyway to apply this as default, and more importantly, can I apply this as default to different states of the JTextField?

```
public class RoundJTextField extends BasicTextFieldUI {
private int round = 5;
private int shadeWidth = 2;
private int textSpacing = 3;

public void installUI ( JComponent c )
{
    super.installUI ( c );

    c.setOpaque ( false );

    int s = shadeWidth + 1 + textSpacing;
    c.setBorder ( BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder ( s, s, s, s ) );
}

protected void paintSafely ( Graphics g )
{
    Graphics2D g2d = ( Graphics2D ) g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint ( RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON );

    Shape border = getBorderShape ();

    Stroke os = g2d.getStroke ();
    g2d.setStroke ( new BasicStroke ( shadeWidth * 2 ) );
    g2d.setPaint ( new Color(220,220,220) );
    g2d.draw ( border );
    g2d.setStroke ( os );

    g2d.setPaint ( new Color(176,176,176) );
    g2d.fill ( border );

    g2d.setPaint ( new Color(0,0,0) );
    g2d.draw ( border );

    super.paintSafely ( g );
}

private Shape getBorderShape ()
{
    JTextComponent component = getComponent ();
    if ( round > 0 )
    {
        return new RoundRectangle2D.Double ( shadeWidth, shadeWidth,
                component.getWidth () - shadeWidth * 2 - 1,
                component.getHeight () - shadeWidth * 2 - 1, round * 2, round * 2 );
    }
    else
    {
        return new Rectangle2D.Double ( shadeWidth, shadeWidth,
                component.getWidth () - shadeWidth * 2 - 1,
                component.getHeight () - shadeWidth * 2 - 1 );
    }
}
```

}

Currently to set the JTextField I am using:

```
snTF = new JTextField(tfW); 
snTF.setUI(new RoundJTextField());
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class that extends `JTextField`, and in the constructor call the methods you currently call that setup the UI of your current `JTextField`s, and then instead of creating `JTextField`s you then just create `MyJTextField`s which will have by default your custom effects.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Nimbus, you can implement the `Painter` interface ([javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Painter.html)). You can then assign your custom painters to properties in the `UIDefaults` class (obtained from `UIManager.getDefaults()`). For example, to change the border for a JTextField when moving the mouse over it, set the `TextField[MouseOver].borderPainter` property to your own `Painter`. The Nimbus Look and Feel will delegate painting the border to your `Painter` when the mouse is over the textfield.

Sources: [Nimbus: The New Face of Swing - Jasper Potts](http://cache.jasperpotts.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/08/ps_ts-6096-nimbus.pdf) (from page 27 onwards)